# R: compare vector and get false when true is expected

Tags: r

I compare the vector with fixed value and expect the third one to be `TRUE` in `R`. However, I got all `FALSE`. Could someone explain why.

```
> seq(0.20, 0.40, 0.05) == 0.3
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
> seq(0.20, 0.40, 0.05) == 0.30
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [var() is not equal to sd()^2 in R](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/590123/var-is-not-equal-to-sd2-in-r)

Comment: An earlier variant, from 2011, out of historical curiosity: [Why is R giving a bad result of addition?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/9269/why-is-r-giving-a-bad-result-of-addition)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why are these numbers not equal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9508518/why-are-these-numbers-not-equal) An example with a sequence containing 0.3 is also on page 9 of the [The R Inferno](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&opi=89978449&url=https://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwj__r2IlPiDAxWAZkEAHX5GCp8QFnoECA8QAQ&usg=AOvVaw3ccYVJrqViLKxffdLT6tdj)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been in the [R FAQ](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-doesn_0027t-R-think-these-numbers-are-equal_003f) for more than 25 years.  The issue is that R (like basically any computer system) represents those numbers in binary floating point.  0.3 cannot be represented exactly in binary, so you'll end up with some sort of best approximation, which is quite likely to be different for numbers computed in different ways

It's useful to look at the size of the differences

```
> seq(0.20, 0.40, 0.05) - 0.30
[1] -1.000000e-01 -5.000000e-02  5.551115e-17  5.000000e-02  1.000000e-01
```

The difference is very small, but it's not zero.